# Is it grammatically correct to say "it is itself something"?

Tags: grammaticality

Just read a sentence from a book:

> It is itself an emitter.

That "itself" reads weird to me. I wonder if it is grammatically correct?

And what's the difference with "it is an emitter."?

Comment: Provided _emitters_ has been part of the previous context. Otherwise, the next paragraph has to discuss the term; but it should have been done before referring to it emphatically.

Comment: You can add "reflexive intensifier" ***itself*** before, after, or anywhere within ***It is an emitter*** - except *It is an itself emitter*, which no amount of contrived context will make acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

Itself, herself, himself, themselves when used in that manner make reference to an *earlier* remark or to an extant context, often to point out some kind of inconsistency or discord.  (So you should look at the sentence(s) preceding the one you quoted since you found it in a text.)

> She chides her neighbors for not being sufficiently eco-conscious, but she is **herself** not as conscientious as she could be in that regard. The landscape crew she hires use equipment powered by two-stroke engines that release lots of so-called "greenhouse" gases.
>
> The car comes with an armor-plated body and the window glass  itself is designed with a high level of safety in mind; it is bullet-proof.

You might be surprised to learn that the vehicle's designers had that degree of concern for occupant safety. *Even the window glass* is designed with safety in mind.

Comment: It's interesting that you chose to put the reflexive pronoun after the verb in your first example, but after the subject noun in the second. But I don't think it would make any difference if you'd written *but **she herself** is not as conscientious...*, or *the window glass **is itself** designed with...*

Comment: There is no inconsistency or discord in your second example. *Even* does not indicate either of those two concepts with regard to any ideas in the previous text.

Comment: @Araucaria:  I would say that "even" refers to something unexpected or unusual, which is a kind of "discord" if that word is understood in the broadest sense.

Comment: @Tim You could argue every sentence or utterance is a type of discord. No explanatory value. And, anyhow, *even* certainly doesn't signify discord with anything earlier in the text. In fact, *even* tells us that something was even *more* as described than one may have thought. The very, very opposite of discord with what has previously been said. (Consider "It was enormous. Its head even popped out of the roof!" or "He was very generous. He even payed for my flight home.")

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I would reject the *ad absurdum*  reduction "every sentence or utterance is a type of discord" . I would say that **even** refers to a departure from some norm and as such is a kind of inconsistency or discord. The inconsistency or discord need not be in direct relation with the assertion in the previous sentence (not an adversative) but in the *context* established by the prior assertion: "The day was the hottest on record. The shade itself seemed to be looking for shade."  Even the shade was looking for shade.

Comment: @Tim Your weaseling. The function of *even* is to signal the very opposite of discord with what has previously been said. Thus it is the very opposite of what you have written in your post!!!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore.  You're taking the inconsistency to be *between* the assertion in the previous sentence and the assertion in the following sentence. That is  just one kind of inconsistency, as shown in my first example about eco-consciousness, where there is a kind of hypocrisy.  In the second example, with the car and bullet-proof glass, and in my comment with the shade on the hottest day on record, even when the second statement is in full *accord* with the first, the reflexive signals some departure from a norm, an inconsistency or discord.

Comment: *He himself would have to say it was beautiful.* Even *he* would have to say it was beautiful, though he is (normally) not one to say it was beautiful.

Comment: @Tim a) that's not what you say in your post b) what you now claim is so wishy-washy it has no value to anybody.

Comment: @Araucaria OK, what does the reflexive signal on a semantic level in *He himself would have to say it was beautiful?* Put it into words in a general way that might apply to many situations, and for someone who might not understand what English **even** means. And if you say "for emphasis" I will use your own phrase "so wishy-washy it has no value to anybody".

Comment: Oh, if only I knew!

Comment: I myself have no dog in this fight.  [but others may].